# Google Apps Script - Variable Passed Between Functions Shows Up as Undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some code where there are some if/else if statements to determine the reason that a Google Form has closed. I want to pass this reason to another function which will send an email notifying me that the form has closed and the why. I don't know why the reason, which should be a string, is not getting passed to the function that sends the email.

I'm not dealing with the form at all in this code. For simplicity, I opened a new standalone script, not linked to any Google Form or Sheet, to test just this portion (determine reason and send email). Here is the code:

First function to determine reason the form closed and to call second function to send email:

```
function FindReason() {
  var Day1Seats = 5;
  var Day2Seats = 5;
  var Day1Responses = 6;
  var Day2Responses = 1; 
  var FormClose = false;

  if(Day1Responses >= Day1Seats) {
    var reason = "All seats taken for Day 1";
    SendAnEmail(reason);
  }
  else if(Day2Responses >= Day2Seats) {
    var reason = "All seats taken for Day 2";
    SendAnEmail(reason);
    }
  else if(FormClose) {
    var reason = "Form close date";
    SendAnEmail(reason);
  }
}
```

Second function, which sends email (email address obviously changed for privacy):

```
function SendAnEmail(closereason) {

  var recipientTO = "name@example.com";
  var subject = "This is the subject";
  //var closereason = "All seats taken for Day 1";

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientTO,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: (new Date()) + "<br>Your form has been closed because: <br>" + closereason + "<br>End of message."
  });
}
```

When I run FindReason(), I do get an email but the body doesn't properly show the reason. This is an example of the emails I get:

Sun Feb 24 2019 12:26:01 GMT-0800 (PST)
Your form has been closed because: 
undefined
End of message.

I don't know why the reason is shown as undefined. I tried setting the reason inside the SendAnEmail function (the line that has been commented out) and that worked properly, but I need to be able to change the reason.

Edit: It works now. It turns out the "run" button was set to run the "SendAnEmail" function rather than the "FindReason" function. Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions.

Comment: `if(FormClose = TRUE) {` is an assignment. Try `if(FormClose)`

Comment: Thanks. I fixed this, as also suggested below by Dan, but the problem is still there. Still shows as undefined.

Comment: You haven't updated all of the question code.

Comment: I've updated the question code now.

Comment: It works for me now.

Comment: Yes it works for me as well. I've updated the question. It turns out another issue was that I didn't check which function was running. The "run" button was set to the "SendAnEmail" function instead of the "FindReason" function.

Comment: It would be good to wrap the function body with an `if(closereason)` or use `var closereason = closereason || 'some default value';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's probably happening is that  `else if(FormClose = TRUE)` is not going to work.

1. `=` is the assignment operator, you want equality, which is `===`.
2. `TRUE` is lowercase in js, so you want `true`.
3. You also use `False`, which should be `false`.

If you look in the google scripts editor's console, you should see an error of some sort, because it won't know what `False` or `TRUE` are (it will think they are undeclared variables).

try `else if(FormClose === true)` or even more simply, `else if (FormClose)`, because if it evaluates to true, that will do the job.

```
function FindReason() {
  var Day1Seats = 5;
  var Day2Seats = 5;
  var Day1Responses = 6;
  var Day2Responses = 1; 
  var FormClose = false;

  if(Day1Responses >= Day1Seats) {
    var reason = "All seats taken for Day 1";
    SendAnEmail(reason);
  } else if(Day2Responses >= Day2Seats) {
    var reason = "All seats taken for Day 2";
    SendAnEmail(reason);
  } else if(FormClose) {
    var reason = "Form close date";
    SendAnEmail(reason);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried:"true" and "false" to lowercase, used <code>===</code>

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow. I had issues with the comment above. And I'm not sure if html tags work in comments. Anyway I tried changing "true" and "false" to lowercase; using "===" instead of "="; and also tried "else if(FormClose)". The email still shows the reason as undefined.

Comment: Sure, welcome btw. Your function should work as corrected as long as a string is passed into reason. Just to check your testing, you are running `FindAReason`in the editor, not `SendAnEmail`?

Comment: I assumed I was. I assumed it would run the first function at the top of the code but after you asked, I checked and nope, it was set to "SendAnEmail". I was too busy looking for errors in the code and did not think to check that.  *hang head in shame* It works now. Thank you.

Comment: Great! I can't tell you how many times I've torn apart code because it wouldn't work, only to discover the problem was something in my tests, not my code at all. Have a good evening, and welcome to stackoverflow.